# A spinner inside ExpandableListView group

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview, android-spinner

In my project i implemented a spinner inside each group of an expandable listview and still the group item is expandable

The problem started when i fill the the spinner using a Cursor adapter. the group item and its indicator become unclickable so they are not opening
The group has a custom layout which contain a checkbox both views  already set as focasable=false

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    Call call = (Call) getGroup(i);
    if (view == null) {
       LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_call,null);
    }
    TextView textViewCallProductName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    Spinner spinnerCallPurpose = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerCallReason);
    dbHelper mDb = new dbHelper (context);
    mDb.open();
    Cursor c = mDb.getPurposes();
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,c,new String[]{"purpose_name"},new int[]{android.R.id.text1} );
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerCallPurpose.setAdapter(adapter);
    if ( call.product == null ){
        textViewCallProductName.setText("Null");
    }
    else{
        textViewCallProductName.setText(call.product.name);}
    return view;
}
```

and here is the group layout simple_expandable_list_item_call.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:paddingLeft="50dp">

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/text1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:textAlignment="viewStart"
          android:text="gfg"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Samples"
    android:id="@+id/textView26"/>



<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Reason"
    android:id="@+id/textView19"/>

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinnerCallReason"
        android:prompt="@string/select_purpose"
        android:focusable="false"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Giveaway"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:checked="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Options include:

1)Subclassing Spinner and overriding whatever drives the popup dialog
2)Copying Spinner into your project and replacing whatever drives the popup dialog (if overriding will not work due to method visibility, etc.)
3)Don't use a Spinner, and instead use a Button plus an AlertDialog containing an ExpandableListView, or something like that

Comment: These are alternatives not solutions of the problem. and some are already implemented but it is a matter of UI

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting the following property in parent layout of your group item xml:

> android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"